# Avoiding Duplicate Rows

Tags: mysql

I am working on winform and I have set a timer so that my table gets updated in every 5 mins. In every 5 min, data from table1 is inserted into table2. But I do not want same row inserted twice. This is not a user input so I cannot even place validation. I have written a query for that but it does not work. I know my way of writing query is wrong. Please correct my query.

I dont want procedures. I just want to query in the same manner.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DIPAYN;Initial Catalog=Highway;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Alert(vehicle_no) SELECT vehicle_no FROM Entry WHERE next_expected_time <= GetDate() AND WHERE NOT EXISTS(select alert_id from Alert where alert_id = vehicle_no) ";

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    Error = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                    Error = -1;

                }
                finally { conn.Close(); }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just add a UNIQUE constraint on the table

Comment: both the table have primary keys entry_id and alert_id. If the next_expected_time in Entry table is lesser than Get Date, then only it should update. But you see , in next iteration, the condition will still be same. It will again be lesser than GetDate and get inserted once again. I just want to avoid it the second time. I dont think you understood me. Please try :(

Comment: 'Please try' - funny

Answer (score 1):

You can say that when a duplicate is found, update instead

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Edit:
If you just want to miss out duplicates

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3);
```

Comment: can we say  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE null;

Comment: See edited answer if you just want to ignore duplicates